# Как принять переменные из php в js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Как принять переменные из `php` в `js`. Нужно принять ***4*** переменные с `php` и записать их в соответствующей переменные в `js`. Допустим переменная `*p*` должная равняться `$p;` если просто передать через `echo`, то они передадутся все как одна переменная.

```
<?php 
  $p=123;
  $p2=2123;
  $p3=3342;
  $p4=423423;
  //echo $p;
  //echo $p2;
  //echo $p3;
  //echo $p4;
?>

var p;
var p2;
var p3;
var p4;

$.ajax({ // сам метод ajax
    url: "ppp.php", // куда отправлять данные 
    type: "POST", // метод отправки данных 
    data: ({}), // ничего не отправляем
    dataType: "html", // тип отправки сообщения
    beforeSend: funcBefore, // пока документ загружается эта фун выполняется
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "00000") { 
        // тут нужно принять запрос   
        } else {
            //data=?
            alert(p);
            alert(p2);
            alert(p3);
            alert(p4);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод в PHP:

```
echo json_encode([
'p' => $p,
'p2' => $p2,
'p3' => $p3,
'p4' => $p4
]);
```

Прием в JS:

```
...
success:  function(data){
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   p = data['p'];
   p2 = data['p2'];
...
```